# jQuery validation not validating onkeyup

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

Can someone help me understand why onkeyup validation is not working? I have been staring at it too long! Thanks.

[JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/TheRealPapa/2mgdH/)

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    jQuery('#DSH0000000146FF').validate({
        rules: {
            dish_name: {
                required: true
            },
            dish_description: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            dish_name: {
                required: "Please enter a name, no longer than 80 characters."
            },
            dish_description: {
                required: "Please enter a description, no longer than 240 characters."
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
        if(jQuery('#DSH0000000146FF').validate()){
                 alert("SUBMITTED!");
         }
         else{
           }
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: What youre missing is this validation works after submitting. Since there's no `submit` button in your `form`, it can't work with the way it is :) Just add a submit button to your form

Comment: Your jsfiddle works if you submit the form

Comment: Great, thanks but why does it not validate onkeyup?

Comment: Because you never told it to do that.

Comment: You can use the .keyup function to do that.

Answer (score 1):

Add `submit button`  to form

```
<textarea id="DSH0000000146d" name="dish_description" 
      class="textarea-comment dish_description" maxlength="240">More testing
</textarea><br/>
<input type="submit"></input> <!-- Add this line -->
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chetangawai/2mgdH/15/)

Comment: You have not attached `keyup` event with it

Comment: Thanks! But I thought keyup was default on?

Comment: If it answers your question don't forget to accept it

Comment: Hi Miss Chetan Gawai, it does not work as I want to. I thought onkey up was default "true" and meant it will validate the field onblur?